# Launch screen is not being presented for iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having issues displaying an image as a launch screen. I have added some images that will walk you through what I have done.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to not use Launch Image and use the Launch Screen instead, since you can use auto layout and support **any screen size**, including iPad multitasking, or new devices released in the future.

However, if you really want to use the Launch Image, seems like iOS9 requires different launch images for each device orientation. That might be your issue.

> iOS 9 enforces the UILaunchImages requirement; apps can no longer
>   declare the same launch image to support different interface
>   orientations.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-9.0

Comment: Yes. I can do this by adding a Launch Screen file, importing the launch image icon into the Xcode project, then by dragging an image view object I can set that background to the image I have imported. I'll post an answer shortly.